# Audio Unit Graph pause and repeating

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio

I've been trying to implement Audio Unit Graph using Apple provided code:
[IphoneMixerEQGraphTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest/Introduction/Intro.html). So far I have encountered two problems:

1.) I can't find any way to pause playing

2.) Provided example repeats endlessly. Is There a way I can disable repeat or or stop it - using a timer, intercept some kind of buffer value, when playing is almost at the end?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO REPEATING FUNCTIONALITY**

So far I have found a way to deal with audio stopping - although it's not pretty:

I load same audio file in AVAudioPlayer - and get from it sound file duration. Then, using

```
performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
```

I can stop AUGraph when sound file should end playing.

**PAUSE AUGRAPH FUNCTIONALITY**

It turns out that implementing pause is pretty simple. While AUGraph data source is not changed - by calling

```
[graphController startAUGraph]; or [graphController stopAUGraph];
```

will only pause/resume playing.

Although this affects performSelector timer. So, to use both - pause/no-repeating possibilities, one should use NSTimer - when AUGraph paused - then timer pauses too. When AUGraph resumed - timer resumes counting, and when it reaches provided sound file duration - it stops playing.

**Bottom line**

By using duration value from AVAudioPlayer (or any other player which provides duration) - it is possible to implement AUGraph sound player with play/pause/stop (no-repeat/repeat)/next song/previous song/ functions + EQUALIZER.

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayer is a huge class, You can easily get duration from:

```
Float64 fileDuration = PrepareFileAU (fileAU, fileFormat, audioFile);
```

see ADC sample at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PlayFile/Introduction/Intro.html

avoiding including other frameworks.