# how to play music with audiounit and augraph in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I am new to AudioUnit and AUGraph services.
My need is to play a single sound file using these sevices.
 I have downloaded MixerHost project from apple's developer site and changed some codes.
But the code is crashing now

my new changed code is:

```
#import "JKAudioPlayer.h"
#pragma mark Mixer input bus render callback

//
//    Declared as AURenderCallback in AudioUnit/AUComponent.h. See Audio Unit Component Services Reference.
static OSStatus inputRenderCallback (

                                     void                        *inRefCon,  
                                     AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags, 
                                     const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,  
                                     UInt32                      inBusNumber,  
                                     UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
                                     AudioBufferList             *ioData   
                                     ) {

    soundStructPtr    soundStructPointerArray   = (soundStructPtr) inRefCon;
    UInt32            frameTotalForSound        = soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].frameCount;
    BOOL              isStereo                  = soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].isStereo;

    AudioUnitSampleType *dataInLeft;
    AudioUnitSampleType *dataInRight;

    dataInLeft                 = soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].audioDataLeft;
    if (isStereo) dataInRight  = soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].audioDataRight;

    AudioUnitSampleType *outSamplesChannelLeft;
    AudioUnitSampleType *outSamplesChannelRight;

    outSamplesChannelLeft                 = (AudioUnitSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    if (isStereo) outSamplesChannelRight  = (AudioUnitSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;

    UInt32 sampleNumber = soundStructPointerArray[0].sampleNumber;

    for (UInt32 frameNumber = 0; frameNumber < inNumberFrames; ++frameNumber) {
        outSamplesChannelLeft[frameNumber]                 = dataInLeft[sampleNumber];
        if (isStereo) outSamplesChannelRight[frameNumber]  = dataInRight[sampleNumber];
        sampleNumber++;
        if (sampleNumber >= frameTotalForSound) sampleNumber = 0;
    }
    soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].sampleNumber = sampleNumber;
    return noErr;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Audio route change listener callback
static void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (
                                              void                      *inUserData,
                                              AudioSessionPropertyID    inPropertyID,
                                              UInt32                    inPropertyValueSize,
                                              const void                *inPropertyValue
                                              ) {
    if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;
    JKAudioPlayer *audioObject = (__bridge_transfer JKAudioPlayer *) inUserData;  
    if (NO == audioObject.isPlaying) {
        NSLog (@"Audio route change while application audio is stopped.");
        return;
    } else {
        CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = inPropertyValue;
        CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef =
        CFDictionaryGetValue (
                              routeChangeDictionary,
                              CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason)
                              );

        SInt32 routeChangeReason;

        CFNumberGetValue (
                          routeChangeReasonRef,
                          kCFNumberSInt32Type,
                          &routeChangeReason
                          );        
        if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable) {

            NSLog (@"Audio output device was removed; stopping audio playback.");
            NSString *MixerHostAudioObjectPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification = @"MixerHostAudioObjectPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification";
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: MixerHostAudioObjectPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object: audioObject]; 

        } else {

            NSLog (@"A route change occurred that does not require stopping application audio.");
        }
    }
}

@implementation JKAudioPlayer
@synthesize monoStreamFormat;           // mono format for use in buffer and mixer input for "beats" sound
@synthesize graphSampleRate;            // sample rate to use throughout audio processing chain
@synthesize mixerUnit;                  // the Multichannel Mixer unit
@synthesize playing;                    // Boolean flag to indicate whether audio is playing or not
@synthesize interruptedDuringPlayback;  // Boolean flag to indicate whether audio was playing when an interruption arrived
- (id) init {

    self = [super init];

    if (!self) return nil;
    NSURL *beatsLoop   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"beatsMono"
                                                 withExtension: @"caf"];
    sourceURL   = (__bridge_retained  CFURLRef) beatsLoop;
    self.interruptedDuringPlayback = NO;
    [self setupAudioSession];    
    [self setupMonoStreamFormat];
    [self readAudioFilesIntoMemory];
    [self configureAndInitializeAudioProcessingGraph];
    [self enableMixerInput: 0 isOn: YES];
    [self setMixerOutputGain:1];
    [self setMixerInput: 0 gain:YES];
    return self;
}
- (void) setupAudioSession {
    AVAudioSession *mySession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [mySession setDelegate: self];
    NSError *audioSessionError = nil;
    [mySession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                     error: &audioSessionError];

    if (audioSessionError != nil) {

        NSLog (@"Error setting audio session category.");
        return;
    }
    self.graphSampleRate = 44100.0;    // Hertz
    [mySession setPreferredHardwareSampleRate: graphSampleRate
                                        error: &audioSessionError];
    if (audioSessionError != nil) {

        NSLog (@"Error setting preferred hardware sample rate.");
        return;
    }
    [mySession setActive: YES
                   error: &audioSessionError];

    if (audioSessionError != nil) {

        NSLog (@"Error activating audio session during initial setup.");
        return;
    }    
    self.graphSampleRate = [mySession currentHardwareSampleRate];
    AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (
                                     kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange,
                                     audioRouteChangeListenerCallback,
                                     (__bridge void*)self
                                     );
}
- (void) setupMonoStreamFormat {
    size_t bytesPerSample = sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType);
    monoStreamFormat.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    monoStreamFormat.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical;
    monoStreamFormat.mBytesPerPacket    = bytesPerSample;
    monoStreamFormat.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
    monoStreamFormat.mBytesPerFrame     = bytesPerSample;
    monoStreamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame  = 1;                  // 1 indicates mono
    monoStreamFormat.mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * bytesPerSample;
    monoStreamFormat.mSampleRate        = graphSampleRate;
}


- (void) readAudioFilesIntoMemory {
    ExtAudioFileRef audioFileObject = 0;
    OSStatus result = ExtAudioFileOpenURL (sourceURL, &audioFileObject);
    if (noErr != result || NULL == audioFileObject) {NSLog(@"error ext audiofile open url %ld",result); return;}
    UInt64 totalFramesInFile = 0;
    UInt32 frameLengthPropertySize = sizeof (totalFramesInFile);
    result =    ExtAudioFileGetProperty (
                                         audioFileObject,
                                         kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames,
                                         &frameLengthPropertySize,
                                         &totalFramesInFile
                                         );

    if (noErr != result) {NSLog(@"ExtAudioFileGetProperty (audio file length in frames %ld",result); return;}
    soundStruct.frameCount = totalFramesInFile;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription fileAudioFormat = {0};
    UInt32 formatPropertySize = sizeof (fileAudioFormat);
    result =    ExtAudioFileGetProperty (
                                         audioFileObject,
                                         kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat,
                                         &formatPropertySize,
                                         &fileAudioFormat
                                         );

    if (noErr != result) {NSLog( @"ExtAudioFileGetProperty (file audio format)%ld",result); return;}

    UInt32 channelCount = fileAudioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    soundStruct.audioDataLeft =
    (AudioUnitSampleType *) calloc (totalFramesInFile, sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType));

    AudioStreamBasicDescription importFormat = {0};
    if (1 == channelCount) {

        soundStruct.isStereo = NO;
        importFormat = monoStreamFormat;

    } else {

        NSLog (@"*** WARNING: File format not supported - wrong number of channels");
        ExtAudioFileDispose (audioFileObject);
        return;
    }
    result =    ExtAudioFileSetProperty (
                                         audioFileObject,
                                         kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                                         sizeof (importFormat),
                                         &importFormat
                                         );

    if (noErr != result) {NSLog( @"ExtAudioFileSetProperty (client data format %ld", result); return;}
    AudioBufferList *bufferList;
    bufferList = (AudioBufferList *) malloc (
                                             sizeof (AudioBufferList) + sizeof (AudioBuffer) * (channelCount - 1)
                                             );

    if (NULL == bufferList) {NSLog (@"*** malloc failure for allocating bufferList memory"); return;}

    bufferList->mNumberBuffers = channelCount;
    AudioBuffer emptyBuffer = {0};
    size_t arrayIndex;
    for (arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < channelCount; arrayIndex++) {
        bufferList->mBuffers[arrayIndex] = emptyBuffer;
    }
    bufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels  = 1;
    bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize    = totalFramesInFile * sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType);
    bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData            = soundStruct.audioDataLeft;

    if (2 == channelCount) {
        bufferList->mBuffers[1].mNumberChannels  = 1;
        bufferList->mBuffers[1].mDataByteSize    = totalFramesInFile * sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType);
        bufferList->mBuffers[1].mData            = soundStruct.audioDataRight;
    }

    UInt32 numberOfPacketsToRead = (UInt32) totalFramesInFile;

    result = ExtAudioFileRead (
                               audioFileObject,
                               &numberOfPacketsToRead,
                               bufferList
                               );

    free (bufferList);

    if (noErr != result) {

        NSLog( @"ExtAudioFileRead failure - %ld " , result);
        free (soundStruct.audioDataLeft);
        soundStruct.audioDataLeft = 0;

        if (2 == channelCount) {
            free (soundStruct.audioDataRight);
            soundStruct.audioDataRight = 0;
        }

        ExtAudioFileDispose (audioFileObject);            
        return;
    }

    NSLog (@"Finished reading file  into memory");
    soundStruct.sampleNumber = 0;
    ExtAudioFileDispose (audioFileObject);
}

- (void) configureAndInitializeAudioProcessingGraph {

    NSLog (@"Configuring and then initializing audio processing graph");
    OSStatus result = noErr;
    result = NewAUGraph (&processingGraph);

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"NewAUGraph" withStatus: result]; return;}

    // I/O unit
    AudioComponentDescription iOUnitDescription;
    iOUnitDescription.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    iOUnitDescription.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    iOUnitDescription.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    iOUnitDescription.componentFlags         = 0;
    iOUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask     = 0;

    // Multichannel mixer unit
    AudioComponentDescription MixerUnitDescription;
    MixerUnitDescription.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Mixer;
    MixerUnitDescription.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer;
    MixerUnitDescription.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    MixerUnitDescription.componentFlags         = 0;
    MixerUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask     = 0;


    //............................................................................
    // Add nodes to the audio processing graph.
    NSLog (@"Adding nodes to audio processing graph");

    AUNode   iONode;         // node for I/O unit
    AUNode   mixerNode;      // node for Multichannel Mixer unit

    // Add the nodes to the audio processing graph
    result =    AUGraphAddNode (
                                processingGraph,
                                &iOUnitDescription,
                                &iONode);

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphNewNode failed for I/O unit" withStatus: result]; return;}


    result =    AUGraphAddNode (
                                processingGraph,
                                &MixerUnitDescription,
                                &mixerNode
                                );

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphNewNode failed for Mixer unit" withStatus: result]; return;}
    result = AUGraphOpen (processingGraph);

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphOpen" withStatus: result]; return;}
     result =    AUGraphNodeInfo (
                                 processingGraph,
                                 mixerNode,
                                 NULL,
                                 &mixerUnit
                                 );

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphNodeInfo" withStatus: result]; return;}
    UInt32 busCount   = 2;    // bus count for mixer unit input

    UInt32 beatsBus   = 1;    // mixer unit bus 1 will be mono and will take the beats sound

    NSLog (@"Setting mixer unit input bus count to: %lu", busCount);
    result = AudioUnitSetProperty (
                                   mixerUnit,
                                   kAudioUnitProperty_ElementCount,
                                   kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                   0,
                                   &busCount,
                                   sizeof (busCount)
                                   );

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AudioUnitSetProperty (set mixer unit bus count)" withStatus: result]; return;}
   UInt32 maximumFramesPerSlice = 4096;

    result = AudioUnitSetProperty (
                                   mixerUnit,
                                   kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice,
                                   kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                   0,
                                   &maximumFramesPerSlice,
                                   sizeof (maximumFramesPerSlice)
                                   );

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AudioUnitSetProperty (set mixer unit input stream format)" withStatus: result]; return;}
    for (UInt16 busNumber = 0; busNumber < busCount; ++busNumber) {

        // Setup the struture that contains the input render callback 
        AURenderCallbackStruct inputCallbackStruct;
        inputCallbackStruct.inputProc        = &inputRenderCallback;
        inputCallbackStruct.inputProcRefCon  = &soundStruct;

        NSLog (@"Registering the render callback with mixer unit input bus %u", busNumber);
        // Set a callback for the specified node's specified input
        result = AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback (
                                              processingGraph,
                                              mixerNode,
                                              busNumber,
                                              &inputCallbackStruct
                                              );

        if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback" withStatus: result]; return;}
    }


    NSLog (@"Setting mono stream format for mixer unit \"beats\" input bus");
    result = AudioUnitSetProperty (
                                   mixerUnit,
                                   kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                   kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                   beatsBus,
                                   &monoStreamFormat,
                                   sizeof (monoStreamFormat)
                                   );

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AudioUnitSetProperty (set mixer unit beats input bus stream format)" withStatus: result];return;}


    NSLog (@"Setting sample rate for mixer unit output scope");
     result = AudioUnitSetProperty (
                                   mixerUnit,
                                   kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate,
                                   kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                   0,
                                   &graphSampleRate,
                                   sizeof (graphSampleRate)
                                   );

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AudioUnitSetProperty (set mixer unit output stream format)" withStatus: result]; return;}
     NSLog (@"Connecting the mixer output to the input of the I/O unit output element");

    result = AUGraphConnectNodeInput (
                                      processingGraph,
                                      mixerNode,         // source node
                                      0,                 // source node output bus number
                                      iONode,            // destination node
                                      0                  // desintation node input bus number
                                      );

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphConnectNodeInput" withStatus: result]; return;}
    CAShow (processingGraph);
    result = AUGraphInitialize (processingGraph);

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphInitialize" withStatus: result]; return;}
}

// Start playback
- (void) startAUGraph  {
     OSStatus result = AUGraphStart (processingGraph);
    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphStart" withStatus: result]; return;}

    self.playing = YES;
}

// Stop playback
- (void) stopAUGraph {
    Boolean isRunning = false;
    OSStatus result = AUGraphIsRunning (processingGraph, &isRunning);
    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphIsRunning" withStatus: result]; return;}

    if (isRunning) {

        result = AUGraphStop (processingGraph);
        if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AUGraphStop" withStatus: result]; return;}
        self.playing = NO;
    }
}

- (void) enableMixerInput: (UInt32) inputBus isOn: (AudioUnitParameterValue) isOnValue {
   OSStatus result = AudioUnitSetParameter (
                                             mixerUnit,
                                             kMultiChannelMixerParam_Enable,
                                             kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                             inputBus,
                                             isOnValue,
                                             0
                                             );

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AudioUnitSetParameter (enable the mixer unit)" withStatus: result]; return;}


}

- (void) setMixerInput: (UInt32) inputBus gain: (AudioUnitParameterValue) newGain {
    NSLog(@"mixer input %lu gain %f",inputBus,newGain);

    OSStatus result = AudioUnitSetParameter (
                                             mixerUnit,
                                             kMultiChannelMixerParam_Volume,
                                             kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                             inputBus,
                                             newGain,
                                             0
                                             );

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AudioUnitSetParameter (set mixer unit input volume)" withStatus: result]; return;}

}
- (void) setMixerOutputGain: (AudioUnitParameterValue) newGain {
    NSLog(@"mixer output  gain %f",newGain);
    OSStatus result = AudioUnitSetParameter (
                                             mixerUnit,
                                             kMultiChannelMixerParam_Volume,
                                             kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                             0,
                                             newGain,
                                             0
                                             );

    if (noErr != result) {[self printErrorMessage: @"AudioUnitSetParameter (set mixer unit output volume)" withStatus: result]; return;}

}
- (void) printErrorMessage: (NSString *) errorString withStatus: (OSStatus) result {

    char resultString[5];
    UInt32 swappedResult = CFSwapInt32HostToBig (result);
    bcopy (&swappedResult, resultString, 4);
    resultString[4] = '\0';

    NSLog (
           @"*** %@ error: %@ %@s",
           errorString,
           (char*) &resultString
           );
}

@end
```

The app crashes at the point

outSamplesChannelLeft[frameNumber]                 = dataInLeft[sampleNumber];
    if (isStereo) outSamplesChannelRight[frameNumber]  = dataInRight[sampleNumber];
 What is the error with my code
Can anyone help me

Comment: If all you need to do is play a single sound, Core-Audio is way overkill. Plus it is hard. Why not try OpenAL - here is a good open source wrapper:https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone

Comment: @skinnyTOD how can I measure the output sound's power with openAL.
I am currently using CDAudiomanager(cocos sound engine). But I can't Measure the output power. I also want to change the pitch of playing sound, this is why because I prefered cocos sound engines instead of AVAudioPlayer. You have any idea about these needs?

Comment: I don't think you can do metering with OpenAL. There are are range of audio options on iOS: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html.

Comment: @skinnyTOD I heared like that. But how does outfit does it for talking tom. That means the mouth sync of tom when he is talking(for smaller sound tom's mouth is less opened for large sound his mouth is widely opend). I want to do something like that

Comment: Its probably a bad memory access.Put in some break points and check the following. 1) both dataIn buffers are not null. 2) sample number does not exceed the buffer size 3) Audiounitsampletype is indeed the sample the correct data size in your buffers and callback. Also if you can post the actual error message it might give a better clue.

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977777/audio-unit-graph-pause-and-repeating

Answer (score 0):

The [following SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300965/how-do-i-connect-an-audiofileplayer-audiounit-to-a-3dmixer) contains working code that plays a single file with Audio Units (even with a mixer inbetween, you may not need that). Even though the question states that it does not work, it worked out of the box for me - just add a `AUGraphStart(_graph)` at the end. It uses the AudioFilePlayer unit, no need to write your own render callback.