# Swift: Triggering sound effects during a timer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

I've created a super simple count down application. You press a button, and the count down runs. The end result calculating looks like this:

- 10.0
- 9.999
- 9.998
- ...

And each whole number represents a second, so as you can imagine it runs fast.

While this loop runs, I have code in it to play a sound if it finds the current values to be 3.0 or 2.0 or 1.0 or 0.0.

Everything triggers and the sound plays, however it is glitchy as heck. About 80% of the time is triggers perfectly. The rest of the time it is either delayed by a fraction of a second or misses it completely. The sound effects are critical to the app.

I've used prepare to play properly and it did nothing to improve. My current implementation is using **SKTAudio** which I feel like is a bit overkill for my needs.

Any advice?

Comment: How about posting some code?

Comment: Maybe look at [Simple low-latency audio playback in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680007/simple-low-latency-audio-playback-in-ios-swift) ?

Answer (score 0):

Please mind one moment - if you are using Double class to compare two values, you may find, that 2.0 value is not real 2.0, but 2.0000000001 for example. So, 2 and 2.0000001 are different values and your sound will no be played

Use may try smth. like

```
let checkValue: Double = 2 // your comparison value
let timerValue = 2.00000001 //for example
if (timerValue - Double(Int(timerValue))) == 0 && checkValue == timerValue {
    print("Cool")
} else {
    print("Not cool")
}
```

or almost the same

```
let checkValue: Double = 2 // your comparison value
let timerValue = 2.00000001 //for example

if timerValue == Double(Int(timerValue)) && timerValue == checkValue {
    print("Cool")
} else {
    print("Not cool")
}
```