# iOS - AVAudioPlayerNode.play() execution is very slow

Tags: ios, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I'm using AVAudioEngine for audio in an iOS game application. A problem I've encountered is that AVAudioPlayerNode.play() takes a long time to execute, which can be a problem in real-time applications such as games.

play() just activates the player node - you don't have to call it every time you play a sound. As such, it doesn't have to be called that often, but it does have to be called occasionally, such as to activate the player initially, or after it's been deactivated (which happens in some situations). Even if only called occasionally, the long execution times can be a problem, especially if you need to call play() on multiple players at once.

The execution time for play() seems to be proportional to the value of AVAudioSession.ioBufferDuration, which you can request to be changed using AVAudioSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(). Here's some code I'm using to test this:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let engine = AVAudioEngine()
    private let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    private let ioBufferSize = 1024.0 // Or 256.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        try! audioSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(ioBufferSize / 44100.0)
        try! audioSession.setActive(true)

        engine.attach(player)
        engine.connect(player, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)

        try! engine.start()

        print("IO buffer duration: \(audioSession.ioBufferDuration)")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if player.isPlaying {
            player.stop()
        } else {
            let startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
            player.play()
            let endTime = CACurrentMediaTime()

            print("\(endTime - startTime)")
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some sample timings for play() that I got using a buffer size of 1024 (which I believe is the default):

```
0.0218
0.0147
0.0211
0.0160
0.0184
0.0194
0.0129
0.0160
```

Here are some sample timings using a buffer size of 256:

```
0.0014
0.0029
0.0033
0.0023
0.0030
0.0039
0.0031
0.0032
```

As you can see above, for a buffer size of 1024, execution times tend to be in the 15-20 ms range (around a full frame at 60 FPS). With a buffer size of 256, it's around 3 ms - not as bad, but still costly when you only have ~17 ms per frame to work with.

This is on an iPad Mini 2 running iOS 12.4.2. This is obviously an old device, but the results I see on the simulator seem similarly proportional, so it seems to have more to do with the buffer size and the behavior of the function itself than with the hardware being used. I don't know what's going on under the hood, but it seems possible that play() blocks until the beginning of the next audio cycle, or something like that.

Requesting a lower buffer size seems like a partial solution, but there are some potential drawbacks. According to the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/OptimizingForDeviceHardware/OptimizingForDeviceHardware.html), lower buffer sizes can mean more disk access when streaming from a file, and irrespective of that, the request may not be honored at all. Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680007/simple-low-latency-audio-playback-in-ios-swift/35245064#35245064), someone reports playback problems related to low buffer sizes. Taking all this into account, I'm disinclined to pursue this as a solution.

That leaves me with execution times for play() in the 15-20 ms range, which typically means a missed frame at 60 FPS. If I arrange things so that only one call to play() is made at a time, and only infrequently, maybe it won't be noticeable, but it's not ideal.

I've searched for information and asked about this in other places, but it seems either not many people are encountering this behavior in practice, or it isn't an issue for them.

AVAudioEngine is intended for use in real-time applications, so if I'm right that AVAudioPlayerNode.play() blocks for a significant amount of time proportional to the buffer size, that seems like a design issue. I realize this probably isn't an issue many are dealing with, but I'm posting here to ask if anyone has encountered this specific issue with AVAudioEngine, and if so, if there's any insight, suggestions, or workarounds anyone can offer.

Comment: Not an answer, but I also find AVAudioPlayerNode.play() to be quite slow to execute. 
I was wondering if you found any workarounds?
Coming from the Web platform, I'm quite surprised that such native functions are actually slower to execute.

Comment: Since there haven't been any answers yet, I'll post an answer soon summarizing my findings.

Comment: I have struggled with the same problem on macOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've investigated this fairly thoroughly. Here are my findings.

Having now tested the behavior on a variety of devices and iOS versions (including the latest version at the time of this writing, 13.2), and having had others test it as well, my current conclusion is that the long execution times for `AVAudioPlayerNode.play()` are inherent and that there's no obvious workaround. As noted in my original post, the execution times can be reduced by requesting a lower buffer duration, but as discussed earlier, this doesn't seem like a viable solution.

I heard from a credible source that calling `play()` on a background thread (e.g. using Grand Central Dispatch) should be safe, and indeed this would be one way to solve the problem. However, although it may technically be safe to call `play()` (or other `AVAudioEngine`-related functions) on different threads, I'm skeptical as to whether this is a good idea (further explanation below).

The documentation doesn't state this as far as I can tell, but `AVAudioEngine` will throw `NSException`'s under various circumstances, which, without special handling, will result in application termination in Swift.

One of the things that will cause an `NSException` to be thrown is if you call `AVAudioPlayerNode.play()` while the engine is not running. Obviously if you only have your own code to worry about, you can take steps to ensure this doesn't occur.

However, iOS itself will sometimes stop the engine of its own accord, for example when an audio interruption occurs. If you call `play()` subsequent to that and before restarting the engine, an `NSException` will be thrown. It's fairly easy to avoid this mistake if all your calls to `play()` are on the main thread, but multithreading complicates the issue and seems like it could introduce the risk of accidentally calling `play()` after the engine has been stopped. Although there may be ways to work around this, multithreading seems to introduce undesirable complexity and fragility, so I've opted not to pursue it.

My current strategy is as follows. For the reasons discussed earlier, I'm not using multithreading. Instead, I'm doing everything I can to reduce the number of calls to `play()`, both overall and per-frame. This includes, among other things, only supporting stereo audio (for various reasons, supporting both mono and stereo can lead to more calls to `play()`, which is undesirable).

Lastly, I also investigated alternatives to `AVAudioEngine`. OpenAL is still supported on iOS, but is deprecated. A custom implementation using low-level APIs such as Audio Queue Services or Audio Units would be a possibility, but would be non-trivial. I've also looked at some open-source solutions, but the options I looked at use `AVAudioEngine` under the hood themselves and therefore suffer from the same problems, and/or have other shortcomings or limitations of their own. Of course there are also commercial options available, which may provide a solution for some developers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer!