# AUAudioFilePlayer silences whole graph after playing

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

In order to play sound fragments from a file, I have setup a Audio Graph with three units, a `AUAudioFilePlayer` unit, a mixer unit, and an output unit, according to the code in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300965/how-do-i-connect-an-audiofileplayer-audiounit-to-a-3dmixer). That works fine, and plays my sound fragments perfectly.

Then I have added another `AUAudioFilePlayer` unit, and fed its output in the mixer as well, so I can play from two files in parallel and mix them together. That also works fine, as long as I keep scheduling fragments on both `AUAudioFilePlayer` units (that is, I have a timer that schedules a new 2-second fragment every 2 seconds). But as soon as I stop scheduling fragments on one of the `AUAudioFilePlayer` units, the whole graph falls silent. My timer still happily schedules a new fragment on the first `AUAudioFilePlayer` unit, and I don't get any errors on any of the system calls, but no sound comes through.

Anybody knows how to prevent this?

I have tried doing an `AudioUnitReset` on the second player, and even to remove it from the graph with `AUGraphDisconnectNodeInput`, all to no avail.

My code to schedule a fragment is here:

```
CheckError(AudioUnitReset(fileAU, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0), "AudioUnitReset");

ScheduledAudioFileRegion rgn;
memset (&rgn.mTimeStamp, 0, sizeof(rgn.mTimeStamp));
rgn.mTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
rgn.mTimeStamp.mSampleTime = -1;
rgn.mCompletionProc = NULL;
rgn.mCompletionProcUserData = NULL;
rgn.mAudioFile = inputFile;
rgn.mLoopCount = 0;
rgn.mStartFrame = startFrame;
rgn.mFramesToPlay = 88200;

CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(fileAU, kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0,&rgn, sizeof(rgn)), "AudioUnitSetProperty[kAudioUnitProperty_ScheduledFileRegion] failed");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the mixer I used. Originally I used the `AU3DMixerEmbedded` which was in the code that I copied. When I replaced that mixer with `MultiChannelMixer`, then everything started to work fine. I still don't know why `AU3DMixerEmbedded` didn't work.