# AUGraph resume after stop

Tags: core-audio

I created a project in which I have included various audio AudioUnit type: generator, mix, highpass, IOU in Augraph enviroments. I can get working almost everything I had planned for the app, but I can not explain why I can hear the fileplayer with the (action auGraphStart), but if I press the action (augraphStop) and then again (auGraphStart) this action does not resume audio. the only thing I can hear after pressing start again is a small chunk of audio and then total silence.

can you put me in right direction to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977777/audio-unit-graph-pause-and-repeating

Comment: thanks attin83 for suggest, I'm study on for possible solution...